# search range data on CSV file using java

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to get selective data from .csv file using java.

for example:

CSV file contains:

```
Blue, 03/11/2014, 13:00, 10
pink, 04/11/2014, 14:00, 15
Red, 03/11/2014, 15:00, 50
```

I want to create a program in java which will allow users to select what info they want from that file.

I've been working on the example below but only able to print strings and not the dates/intergers:

```
package csv;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReadCVS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ReadCVS obj = new ReadCVS();
        obj.run();

    }

    public void run() {

        String csvFile = "GeoIPCountryWhois.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        File file = new File("GeoIPCountryWhois.csv");
        Scanner in = null;

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] colour = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                //System.out.println(country[0]+ country[1] + country[2]+ country[3]);

                for (int i = 0; i < colour.length; i++) {
                    if (colour[i].equals("Pressure")) {
                        System.out.println(colour[0] + colour[1] + colour[2] + colour[3]); //Matching    the string and printing.
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

Any help/tips will be appreciated!

thanks

Comment: Question is vague, please explain more.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using 3rd party library for parsing the csv file. This lets you focus on the essence of what you are trying to do, instead of getting hung up on file parsing. Have a look at, for example [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html). This would let your code look like this:

```
Reader in = new FileReader("GeoIPCountryWhois.csv");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String colour = record.get(0);
    Date date = df.parse(record.get(1));
    String timeString = record.get(2);
    Integer value = Integer.parseInt(record.get(3));
    // do what you want with the values here.
}
```

Notice how this does some additional parsing, such as parsing the `Date` and the `Integer`. This will let you more easily filter those columns because you can do comparisons.

If you don't want third party dependencies, you could do something similar to what you have:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // use comma as separator
    String[] columns = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

    // extract the columns.
    String colour = columns[0].trim();
    Date date = df.parse(columns[1].trim());
    String time = columns[2].trim();
    Integer otherValue = Integer.parseInt(columns[3].trim());

    // filter on the colour column.
    if(colour.equals("Red")) {
        System.out.printf("colour = %s, date = %s, time = %s, val = %d\n", colour, df.format(date), time, otherValue);
    }

}
```

Note how this code is calling `String.trim()` on all of the columns. This is in case there is extra whitespace around the column after splitting the line. For example, `"a, b, c".split(",")` would result in the `String` array `{"a", " b", " c"}` which has an extra space in `" b"` and `" c"`. This is probably the source of the bug you have where you can only filter on the first column.

As a third option, which is sort of overkill, you could use [CsvJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/). This provides a JDBC interface to sql files, which you can then execute SQL queries over. I've never used this library but it looks interesting. Given that you are trying to filter CSV files.